# How can I make a combobox stay open after an item has been selected?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

How do I make a combobox stay open after an item is selected in C#?

I want to do this because it is actually a comboBox with a checklist so I can select several items.

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? MVC? WPF? Why do you need it to "stay open"?

Comment: winform. i need it for something...

Comment: for something. That does tell me so much. I am asking because depending on the reason, a different, better solution might be found.

Comment: What you really need is a `ListView`, with its [`CheckBoxes` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx) set to "True".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ListBox` instead of a ComboBox.  What you want to do (keep a ComboBox open even after the user has selected a choice) would be unusual and unexpected behavior.

**Update:**  I think this sample will let you do what you want (which is to have a multi-select list that only takes up the form real estate of one control):

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/treeview/article.php/c15373/

Comment: the link is broken. please provide an explanation of the article.

Answer (score 5):

Use [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) instead, since `ComboBox` does that behavior by its core design.

`ListBox` gives a similar effect (hence it is still open) and enabling for multi-selection.

Comment: **No it doesn't**. A *drop-down* combobox does that by its core design, but that's not a necessary feature of *all* comboboxes. There are three different styles available: simple, drop-down, and drop-down list. You can see more information and screen shots [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775791.aspx).

Comment: @Code Gray Ok, but there is no one of the styles lefts the menu open.

Comment: Really? Take another look at the "simple" style. It's a textbox sitting on top of a listbox, the first "usercontrol" found in the wild. (And hence the name "combobox", a "combo" of two other boxes.)

Answer (score 4):

If you still want to allow the user to write an option of his own you can still use a DropBox, just set the DropDownStyle property to simple. You'll get something similar with a ListBox but with an TextBox on the top where the user can write somwthing.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is available in .NET 3.0 and beyond.  Use the [ComboBox.StaysOpenOnEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.staysopenonedit.aspx) property

Comment: ComboBox.StaysOpenOnEdit does not address the OP's problem. From the linked documentation: The "control will remain open when a user clicks the TextBox" (the TextBox is the portion of the control where the user can type into, not the popup part with the selection).

Answer (score 1):

While I realize the question was intended for winforms, please allow me to contribute an answer for wpf seekers(as I got here, actually).

simply put something like this in the combo box.

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Width="1" Height="1" IsDropDownOpen="{Binding ElementName=TButton,Path=IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Grid Width="200" Height="400" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Margin="-5" IsHitTestVisible="True">
            <Button Background="Transparent"></Button> <--------- This is the equivalent of a e.handled
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Button 1"/>
                <Button Content="Button 1"/>
                <Button Content="Button 1"/>
                <Button Content="Button 1"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ComboBox>
   <ToggleButton x:Name="TButton" Content="Drop" MaxHeight="40" MaxWidth="40"/>
</Grid>
```

Quick and dirty fix for a decent, hassle free drop down control.

When you click the combobox item, you actually click the invisible button and the combo stays open.

I've tried with a hittest visible rect, but no dice. This does the trick.

*Note*

---

One should replace the invisible background with a style that completely strips the button (when mouse is over or a click is performed).

Also, a drop font icon / path instead of *drop* would be nice. :)

I **apologize** again for posting here. I've been looking all over the place for a quick drop down control with 0 outside dependencies(popup won't do) and all I've stumbled across are ridiculously (needlessly) complicated implementations. I hope this will steer somebody in the right direction!

Best of luck to you!

**Edit**
A simple opacity 0 will do. Doh...